# Proving uniqueness of solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was presented to a solution of following second-order linear ordinary differential equation

$$y''=k^2y$$

In solving the equation, they assume a solution will be proportional to $e^{\lambda t}$ for some constant $\lambda$, thereby substituting $y=e^{\lambda t}$, yielding the general solution

$$y=c_1 e^{kt} + c_2 e^{-kt}$$

It does not, however mention why (or if at all) this is the only solution. I was wondering how I can prove the uniqueness of this solution?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the equation is linear and homogenous, so:

$$
(D^2-k^2)y = 0
\\(D-k)(D+k)y = 0
$$

I'm sure you can handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Let define the following map: $$Y:=\begin{pmatrix}y'\\y\end{pmatrix}.$$
Let define the following matrix: $$A:=\begin{pmatrix}0 & k^2\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$
One has: $$y''=k^2y\Leftrightarrow Y'=AY.$$
Notice that: $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R},\exp(-xA)(Y'(x)-AY(x))=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}(Y(t)\exp(-tA))_{\vert t=x}.$$
Finally, one has: $$y''=k^2y\Leftrightarrow Y=\exp(tA)\begin{pmatrix}c_1\\c_2\end{pmatrix}.$$

One has to compute $\exp(-tA)$, for that notice that: $$A^2=k^2I_2.$$

*Remark.* You might be interested in [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), this is unnecessary machinery here, though.